# Where do I go to make a web portfolio?

Tags: website-design, portfolio

So I have been doing webdesign or web development as a hobby for two years and recently I made a leap to make it a career and even went back to school for it. I've done two projects, one which fell through but I still have all the code I did for them. Another project I am doing and the website is live and running which is great I have some experience and schooling however...

I don't know where to go to make a portfolio and I am strapped for cash as I have enough to pay bills and make sure my kid is fed.

I know there are few website hosts but they are generally limited I found to let me actually show off my coding skills. But I am just starting out so I was wondering what do many of you recommend I do to start a portfolio? Use a free hosting? Or do I need to buy actual hosting?

Comment: Personal opinion: if you want to make a career out of your web skills... pay for hosting. You can get a small hosting package for generally around $5 a month. Free hosting just tells EVERYONE you aren't that serious. In fact, so non-serious that it's not even worth $5 a month to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the quickest way to get a portfolio up and running is with Wordpress. Wordpress is usually supported well by hosting companies, meaning that you can set up a Wordpress site with just a few clicks.

For more on this just Google for something like "setting up Wordpress site". You should find plenty of options.

Don't use Wordpress' offer to host your blog for free, last I checked you can only use some limited amount of themes on their site.

You'll have to search on Google for "free wordpress portfolio themes", there are many available. Pick one you like, set it on your Wordpress instance, and fill it up with your work.

Get a paid host, they're cheap (around $5/mo). Read reviews about the host you're considering to buy first, to see others' opinion of them. You'll also want to pick a professional-sounding domain name that's to represent your business. Your name works ok, if the domain is available. Aside from ".com" there's also ".studio" and ".design" which come relatively cheap (they're paid yearly).

Look into "SEO" to make sure you're pairing your work with relevant descriptions on your portfolio, so that your work has a chance to come up when people search Google for related keywords.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing websites, presumably good quality responsive websites, i say don't bother to show off your *coding* skills but instead just present the actual end product. Good websites are easy to spot, even to somebody who cannot dig into your source code. Then, get a free Behance account first and market the work like [these guys](https://www.behance.net/gallery/53239299/Chambres-dHotes-_Web-Design) are doing (just a random example), showing actual screens on different devices and so on.

Are they showing any code? No. But the screens look like they probably know what they're doing.

Comment: Yes, definitely no need to show code. I mean who's there to evaluate it? Your prospective clients? Unless you want to work for other developers, they won't even know what's going on in there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of websites that offers web servers for as low as $5/m but if you are not willing to spend money a month on web servers I would recommend creating your portfolio on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

You can have one website per account and it's free. You can just download a theme or create your own site for your portfolio and upload to your repository.